# Excel: How to create multiple records from a single record

Tags: microsoft-excel, database

I have a database of several companies. There is one record per company. Within each company record, there are multiple contacts.

How can I create a record for each CONTACT (preserving all the same company information for each)?

Here is a sample:

[image: Sample line of data - one company, multiple contact names/emails]

Comment: Are these the exactly columns on your workbook? Your example shows what appears to be 4 contacts but 1 doesn't have an e-mail address field (column *SM*). Is that correct?

Comment: That was an example... and I accidentally hid the SM column. There are actually 6 or 7 email addresses and many other fields. I haven't purchased the database yet, but I want to be prepared to prepare it for import into my CRM when I do.

Comment: OK. I'm sure this can be done in Excel, but it would be easier in Access (assuming you know how to use Access).

Comment: I agree with Twisty. A database is the way to go. It's the single most common problem that everyone wants Excel to be a database, it's just that it's not. It's a spreadsheet with lots of "tricks". Basically you have to add an extra row beneath each contact and duplicate the information on each. In your example it's 3 contacts? So you'd need two rows inserted below and then duplicate (copy) the information down. But you want this automated right? If you're not a programmer, sometimes it's just a long task as most tasks in Excel is.

Comment: Another thing about keeping a database, which is what you are after, is all fields have to be the same for each Company or each record (row). What you show is a single record with multiple custom fields. A normal record for contact information is Name, Address, City, State, Zip, Phone, eMail, Alt Phone, Notes. Or similar. Like I said you give a fake sample so I don't know what type of record keeping skills you have. I'm pretty sure you'd have to just start cranking this out manually. One thing I do is start with small Macros (eg move down, insert two rows, move down 3 times... as start point).

Comment: With VBA routines, you can organize the database however you want. I'd probably create an object for the company data, and include a collection of contact data as one of the properties.  But this can be done many ways.  As others have suggested, a real database program might be simpler, and/or more flexible.

Answer (score 3):

This will suffice for your example. You will need to modify a bit to match the real database.

```
Example Data

Company | Address | City  | State | ZIP | Phone | GM | EmailGM | PD | EmailPD | SM | EmailSM | PRM | EmailPRM
ABC     | 1234 M  | Saint | MN    | zip | phone | gm | gm1@gm  | pd | pd1@pd  | sm | sm1@sm  | prm | prm@prm

Result

Company | Address | City  | State | ZIP | Phone | Name | Email
ABC     | 1234 M  | Saint | MN    | zip | phone | gm   | gm1@gm
ABC     | 1234 M  | Saint | MN    | zip | phone | pd   | pd1@pd
ABC     | 1234 M  | Saint | MN    | zip | phone | sm   | sm1@sm
ABC     | 1234 M  | Saint | MN    | zip | phone | prm  | prm1@prm

Company column (and Address, City, State, ZIP, Phone)
=INDIRECT("A"&(CEILING((ROW()+1)/4-1, 1)))

Name column (and Email)
=INDIRECT(CHAR(CODE("G")+MOD((ROW()-2), 4)*2)&CEILING((ROW()-1)/4+1, 1))
```

### Explanation

At the Company column, the formula refers to `"A"` column and the row number is calculated from the current row.

`ROW()-1` adjusts the row number back, because we have header in the data table. We use number **1** because the data table data starts at row **2**, instead of row **1**.

`/4 + 1` basically copies the result row **4 times**, then adjust the result row number forth by one, because we have header in the data table. We use number **4** because we have *4 names and emails*. We use number **1** because the data table data starts at row **2**, instead of row **1**.

`CEILING( ... , 1 )` rounds the row number up to an integer.

---

At the Name column, the formula refers to the `"G"` column and the row number is calculated from the current row.

`(ROW()-2)` shifts the result of `MOD` back to `0`. We use number **2** because the result table data starts at row **2**.

`MOD( ... , 4)` calculates which column to get. Result of `0` means column `G`, `1` means column `H`, and so on. We use number **4** because we have *4 names and emails*.

`+ ... * 2` shifts the column fetched to the right of column `G` by `the result of modulo, multiplied by 2`. We use number **2** because we have **2** columns, Name and Email, to fetch.

`CODE("G")` converts char "G" to its ASCII code.

`CHAR( ... )` converts the value of shifted column (7 to 11, that is "G" to column "K", for example) back to string.

`CEILING( ... )` gives the data row number to be fetched.

### Instruction

Just change the column letter to the matching column.

*Example:*

for Address column, change the letter `"A"` to `"B"`

for Email column, change the letter `"G"` to `"H"`

### Note

You mentioned you will have *7 names and emails*. You will need to adjust the formula to use 7 instead of 4.

This formula is sensitive to where you put this formula. This formula assumes you will put it on row 2 (row 1 for header). You will need to adjust if you put it on row 1 (see *Explanation*)

This formula does not skip blank name and email. All companies will have exactly 4 rows, regardless of the number of name and email available.

***This is not intended as a substitute to database***, but you can use the data generated by this formula to create the database.

Comment: Wow. Thank you for the thoughtful and thorough response! I understand that Excel is less than optimal. I don't have access to Access - nor do I have the brain to figure out how to do it there either {perhaps I could hire someone...}. The list has a couple thousand names, EACH with up to 7 different contacts. However, in many of these organizations, the same contact may fill multiple roles, so then I'd have an issue of duplicates once I've separated the records. I am going to play with this formula and see if I can master it. THANK YOU SO MUCH!

Answer (score 0):

Another way to do this, in Excel, is with `Power Query` or `Data ► Get and Transform ► From Table` (depends on version of Excel)

After getting into the query editor, select the columns that repeat, and UNPIVOT the other columns.  This will give you a table like this:

[image]

Note that I renamed the new columns that were generated by the UNPIVOT operation.

Now add a third column, label it "Email" and enter this formula in `I2`

```
I2: =IF(ISERR(SEARCH("email",[@Position])),H3,"")
```

[image]

Then it is merely a matter of filtering out the Blanks from the Email column.  You can do that with a simple filter; then copy/paste the visible cells to a results area; or you can use the Advanced Filter, which has a mechanism for sending the results of the filter to a designated area:

[image]